# indexOf within Switch

Tags: javascript, switch-statement, tampermonkey

I have a Javascript-based bot for a Xat chatroom which also acts as an AI. I've recently decided to redo the AI part of it due to it becoming an absolutely massive chain of `else if` statements, becoming nearly impossible to work with.

I did some research and came up with a new idea of how to handle responses. I'll give you the code segment first:

```
function msgSwitch(id,msgRes) {
var botResponse = [];

switch (msgRes) {
  case (msgRes.indexOf("hi") !=-1):
    botResponse.push("HELLO. ");
  case (msgRes.indexOf("how are you") !=-1):
    botResponse.push("I AM FINE. ")
  case (msgRes.indexOf("do you like pie") !=-1):
    botResponse.push("I CAN'T EAT. THANKS, ASSHAT. ")
  default:
    respond (botResponse);
    spamCount(id);
    break;
}

}
```

The idea here is to check `msgRes` (the user's input) and see how many cases it matches. Then for each match, it'll `push` the response into the `botResponse` array, then at the end, it'll reply with all the messages in that array.

**Example**

User Msg: `Hi! How are you?`

msgRes: `hi how are you`

**Bot Matches:**

`hi` > pushes `HELLO.` to array

`how are you` > pushes `I AM FINE.` to array

**Bot Responds:** `HELLO. I AM FINE.`

This in turn saves me the trouble of having to write an `if` for each possible combination.

However, after looking into it some more, I'm not sure if it's possible use `indexOf` inside  of a switch. Does anyone know of a way around this or have a better idea for handling responses in the same manner?

EDIT:

**To Avoid the XY Problem (To clarify my problem)**

I need a clean alternative to using a massive chain of `else if` statements. There are going to be hundreds of word segments that the bot will respond to. Without the ability for it to keep searching for matches, I'd have to write a new `else if` **for every combination**.

I'm hoping for a way to have it scan through every statement for a match, then combine the response for each match together into a single string.

EDIT 2:
I should also add that this is being ran on Tampermonkey and not a website.

Comment: That's totally impossible.  Use `else if`.

Comment: You might want read up again about how `switch` works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My two cents for the gist of what you're trying to do:

```
function msgSwitch(id, msgRes) {
    var seed = {'hi': 'HELLO. ', 'how are you': 'I AM FINE'};
    var botResponse = [];

    for (var key in seed) {
        if (msgRes.indexOf(key) !== -1) {
            botResponse.push(seed[key]);
        }
    }
}
```

In my opinion it is easier to change this program as you only have to edit the seed if you have more responses in the future. You can even stash the seed on some json file and read it (via ajax) so the program does not need to be changed if there are additional messages.

Comment: the parameter `id` is not even used in that function, you can just drop it!

Comment: The next answer properly solves this issue - this answer (while it works) doesn't actually explain why the switch() wasn't working and isn't helpful for others with a similar issue as the OP.

Comment: @Levidps This answer is from 2014 =) and while I have moved on from imperative programming like this - I would like to defend my answer. OP said he wants to avoid a lot of if/else/elseif junctions and I came up with this - the advantages being shorter lines of code, and the seed can be taken away from the program and read via some other means. Being able to change the seed independent of the program is a tenet of configuration - and promotes separation of concerns. As I said, if that seed is from a backend program (REST service), then only the back-end needs to change if there are new messages

Comment: @ailveen missed the part about avoid if/else. I see the validity in using a for loop however I came across this with a similar context and needed to maintain the use of a switch statement. So the second answer was far more helpful to my needs.

Answer (score 40):

you just need to compare to true instead of msgRes (since cases use === comparison), and use break to prevent the annoying fall-though of the switch behavior:

```
function msgSwitch(id,msgRes) {
 var botResponse = [];

 switch (true) {
  case (msgRes.indexOf("hi") !=-1):
    botResponse.push("HELLO. "); break;
  case (msgRes.indexOf("how are you") !=-1):
    botResponse.push("I AM FINE. "); break;
  case (msgRes.indexOf("do you like pie") !=-1):
    botResponse.push("I CAN'T EAT. THANKS, ASSHAT. "); break;
  default:
    respond (botResponse);
    spamCount(id);
    break;
 }

}
```

This is a perfectly valid logical forking pattern, known as an "overloaded switch". A lot of folks might not realize that each `case:` is an expression, not just a value, so you could even put an IIFE in there if needed...

Comment: Very useful answer, especially the 'true' part. Was there a specific reason to encapsulate the case expressions in brackets?

Comment: @DanielBöttner: just to preserve the OP's code as close as possible, they aren't needed.

Comment: 100% this should be the answer. The selected answer is a valid solution but doesn't actually explain why the switch() wasn't working. This properly answers the question, fixes the code, and provides clear details for those with a similar problem.